# sql generate code based on three column values

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have three columns
suppose

```
row no column1 column2 column3
  1      A        B        C
  2      A        B        C
  3      D        E        F
  4      G        H        I
  5      G        H        C
```

I want to generate code by combining these three column values 
For Eg.

```
1)ABC001
2)ABC002
3)DEF001
4)GHI001
5)GHC001
```

by checking combination of three columns

logic is that 
if values of three columns are same then like first time it shows 'ABC001'
and 2nd time it shows 'ABC002'

Comment: ...And turn off your CAPS LOCK!

Comment: And what is the logic behind `001`, `002`, ..... ??

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: Hint... CONCAT, LPAD and MySQL user variables

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

I dont know what you want for logic with 00, but you can add them manuel or let the rn decide for you

```
         declare @mytable table (rowno int,col1 nvarchar(50),col2 nvarchar(50),col3 nvarchar(50)
 )

 insert into @mytable
 values
 (1,'A',       'B',       'C'),
 (2,'A',       'B',       'C'),
 (3,'D',       'E',       'F'),
 (4,'G',       'H',       'I'),
 (5,'G',       'H',       'C')

 Select rowno,col1,col2,col3,

 case when rn >= 10 and rn < 100 then concatcol+'0'+cast(rn as nvarchar(50))
 when rn >= 100 then concatcol+cast(rn as nvarchar(50))
 else concatcol+'00'+cast(rn as nvarchar(50)) end as ConcatCol from (
 select rowno,col1,col2,col3
 ,Col1+col2+col3 as ConcatCol,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by col1,col2,col3 order by rowno) as rn from @mytable
 ) x
 order by rowno
```

My case when makes sure when you  hit number 10 it writes ABC010 and when it hits above 100 it writes ABC100 else if its under 10 it writes ABC001 and so on.

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TSQL: CONCAT(column1,column2,column3,RIGHT(REPLICATE("0", 3) + LEFT(row_no, 3), 3))

Answer (score 0):

You should combine your columns like below :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY
                                              (
                                                  SELECT NULL
                                              )))+') '+DATA AS Data
FROM
(
    SELECT column1+column2+column3+'00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY column1,
                                                                                             column2,
                                                                                             column3 ORDER BY
                                                                               (
                                                                                   SELECT NULL
                                                                               ))) DATA
    FROM <table_name>
) T;
```

**Result :**

```
1)ABC001
2)ABC002
3)DEF001
4)GHI001
5)GHC001
```

Answer (score -1):

MySQL:
CONCAT(column1,column2,column3,LPAD(row_no, 3, '0'))

[you will need to enclose the 'row no' in ticks if there is a space in the name of the field instead of underscore.]